# Connection between homology and homotopy invariants?

Tags: homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

I am interested in understanding the connection between homology and homotopy. In particular, I know that Hurewicz theorem states that for path connected topological spaces we can always find a homomorphism between $H_n(G)$ and $\pi_n(G)$, with $G$ a path connected topological space. If we restrict to $n = 1$, I also know that $H_1(G)\cong \pi^{\rm ab}_1(G)$, i.e. the first homology group is isomorphic to the abelianization of the first homotopy group.
My questions are

- Given Hurewicz theorem, are all homotopy invariants captured by homology? (if G is path connected? What if it isn't?)
- Given $n = 1$, if $\pi_1(G)$ is either trivial or abelian, does it mean that the induced map of the first homology is exactly associated with the elements of that group? (Sorry for the improper language)
- Is the winding number of the determinant map of $G$, the induced map of the first homology?

To make it easier, we can consider a map $f:S^1\to U(N)$. I know that $\pi_1(U(N)) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. I also know that $\pi^{\rm ab}_1(U(N)) = \pi_1(U(N))\cong \mathbb{Z}$, since $\mathbb{Z}$ is abelian. This also mean that $H_1(U(N))\cong \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, is
$f_*:H_1(S^1)\to H_1(U(N))$ the winding number of $det\circ f$?

I apologize if I am not using the correct terminology and/or if I am being not so rigirous. I am sort of new to this topic and I would like a deeper understanding but I can not find direct help in book about topology.

Comment: "are all homotopy invariants captured by homology" No, at least not on the nose. The homology of a space $X$ generally only captures the lowest non-trivial homotopy group of $X$ (if it exists), for instance, even for nice spaces (the homotopy groups of spheres are perhaps the most striking counterexample).

Comment: Your second bullet point I don't understand. What do you mean by "the induced map of the first homology is exactly associated with the elements of that group"? Are you asking whether every group homomorphism $\pi_1(G) \to \pi_1(G)$ is realised as an induced map on $H_1(G)$? Also, the third bullet point: What's the determinant map of a topological space $G$? ...and there as well in the example, I believe you want to be talking about the _degree_ of a map, not the winding number.

Comment: Thank you @BenSteffan for some of the clarifications. I apologize for my improper usage of some terminology. The second and third bullet points are meant to be related in the sense that, if I have, say $\pi_1(U(N)) = \mathbb{Z}$, so here $G = U(N)$. I know that $H_1(U(N)) = \mathbb{Z}$ and that $f=\oint_{\gamma}\frac{dg}{g} = 2\pi i n$, with $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $g:= detU$. Isn't f the induced map of $H_1(U(N))$? If so, given that it is clearly the winding number of $det\circ U$, is it also the topological invariant captured by $\pi_1(U(N))$?

Comment: Your statement of the *Hurewicz Theorem* is flawed. Yes, one can always define a homomorphism $\pi_n(G) \mapsto H_n(G)$, and yes, that homomorphism is named the *Hurewicz homomorphism*. The Hurewicz ***Theorem*** is a statement of properties of the Hurewicz *homomorphism*. There is a separate property for each integer $n \ge 1$. You have (in effect) stated the property for $n=1$, namely that $\pi_1(G)_{ab} \approx H_1(G)$.

Comment: I think I should add also that I can't talk about degree of a map in general because it is only defined between compact topological spaces with the same dimensions.  In the case I mentioned I have a map $h: S^1\to U(N)$ and the degree of such a map is not well defined. However, I can compute the winding number of its determinant which is an integer. Is this the same integer that classifies the elements of $\pi_1(U(N))$? I am just unsure about the topological considerations and the algebraic computation of the topological invariant carried by a map. Does this make sense?

Comment: The statements are different when $n \ge 2$, in particular there are very strong hypotheses in those cases, and when those hypotheses are not satisfied then *all bets are off* about the behavior of the Hurewicz homomorphism $\pi_n(G) \to H_n(G)$.

Comment: The Hurewicz map $h$ is natural, so if $X$ is any path-connected space with abelian fundamental group and $f\colon X \to X$ is a map, then $h \circ \pi_1(f) = H_1(f) \circ h$ tells you these maps are "the same" (under the identification along $h$). In particular (and this is the essence of your example) if $f\colon S^1 \to S^1$ is a map of degree $n$, then both $\pi_1(f)$ and $H_1(f)$ are multiplication by $n$ under the identifications $\pi_1(S^1) \cong H_1(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @LeeMosher, thanks for the clarifications. Indeed, stronger statement can only be made for $n = 1$. I concede that and it is the actual example I need. I was just curious about the generalization to higher $n$.

Comment: @TRay Winding number begs the question of what you're winding around. I would either talk about the induced map on $\pi_1$ outright or restrict to $S^1 \cong U(1) \subseteq U(n)$ and talk about degree (since the inclusion $U(1) \hookrightarrow U(n)$ induces an isomorphism on $\pi_1$).

Comment: So @BenSteffan, sorry if I sound repetitive. I think I understand what you are saying but I still don't have a clear picture of everything. Let me just state the question in a different way then. Given $\pi_1(U(N)) = \mathbb{Z}$, this tells me that all the maps $f:S^1\to U(N)$ are classified by an integer, which is a topological invariant. The problem is what does it represent and how do I compute it. I think it should not be called a degree of a map because the two spaces don't have the same dimension. The only connections I see is what I explained before.

Comment: @TRay You're right that it shouldn't be called "degree" in this form, but observe that my last comment amounts to saying that every such map is _homotopic to a map with image contained in $U(1) \subseteq U(n)$._ So one answer to "what does it represent" is that it represents how often the map wraps around $U(1) \cong S^1$, i.e. it effectively computes the degree of a map $S^1 \to S^1$. As to how to compute it in this particular example, I don't think I have an answer, sorry.

Comment: @BenSteffan, thank you so much. I understand. It seems then that $\pi_1(U(N))$ picks only the $U(1)$ part of the whole group. I guess this makes sense since $U(N)$ is homeomorphic to $S^1\times SU(N)$. As for the actual computation, I can only think of what I mentioned, i.e. the winding number of $det\circ U:S^1\to S^1$ effectively. So it is the degree of that map in your words I believe. My consideration may not work for any group $G$ with nontrivial $\pi_1$ though. Thanks again